# Invoke android context menu on menu item press

Tags: android, android-widget

Can anyone kindly guide as to how can I invoke a context menu on the press of a menu item. I googled a lot for the same, but nothing turned up.
Look forward for your valuable help.
Regards,
Rony

Answer (score 6):

You are probably looking for `openContextMenu(view)`. Call it in your Menu's onclick()

To create a context menu, override `onCreateContextMenu` and `onContextItemSelected`. Refer google for examples.

Comment: Hi, Please let me know what should I give in place of view.... snippet attached here - http://pastebin.com/uh9LXCY2

Comment: Well, it really depends, is it the only context menu in that activity? if it is, then use `getCurrentFocus()`

Comment: No. I have a listview. I debugged and checked .. getCurrentFocus() returns Listview

Comment: @user264953, it seems your using a listactivity, please use `getListView()` make sure you've called `registerForContextMenu(getListView());` and `openContextMenu(getListView())` on you options click. :) good luck!

Comment: What if you are using a standard Activity, not ListActivity, what view would parse in that case?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to implement this function. It will work.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
{
Log.e(LOGTAG, "Tao menu");
if(v == expList)
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    //AdapterContextMenuInfo aInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;

    // We know that each row in the adapter is a Map
    //HashMap map =  (HashMap) simpleAdpt.getItem(aInfo.position);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Options");
    menu.add(1, 1, 1, "Reprint");
    menu.add(1, 2, 1, "Void");

    menu.getItem(0).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener()
    {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem clickedItem)
        {

            return true;
        }
    });

    menu.getItem(1).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener()
    {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem clickedItem)
        {

            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

}